# MongoDB: Unable to find required records

Tags: mongodb

I am new to `MongoDB`. And I have following collections in my MongoDB. My Problem is I am not able to make a find command which gives required facilities based on provided ID or Name.

Find command which I have tried BUT NOT working :-

```
db.mgh_facilities.find({facilities: {$elemMatch: {name: "Foreign exchange assistance"}}}).
```

For me its returning all the records. Shouldn't it be just returning { "id" : "11", "name" : "Foreign exchange assistance" }

My Collections:-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("548acc28ae6ff1c0fd1d7470"),
    "responseCode" : "true",
    "facilities" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "11",
            "name" : "Foreign exchange assistance"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "12",
            "name" : "Assistance with luggage on request"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "13",
            "name" : "24 hours power back-up"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "14",
            "name" : "A/C Power Backup Available"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "15",
            "name" : "swimming pool"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "35",
            "name" : "shoe cleaning service"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "36",
            "name" : "Smoke detectors"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "37",
            "name" : "Fire Extinguishers in each room"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "38",
            "name" : "Pest Control"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "39",
            "name" : "Conference / Banquet Hall"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "45",
            "name" : "Restaurant"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "53",
            "name" : "Anti-slip ramps"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "56",
            "name" : "Tea/ Coffee Maker in the Rooms"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "59",
            "name" : "Wi Fi Internet"
        }
   ]
}
```

Comment: The query Works OK for me

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output you get and your expected output.

Comment: For me its returning all the records. Shouldn't it be just returning                                                             {
            "id" : "11",
            "name" : "Foreign exchange assistance"
        },

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The find command has found the document which contains the facility object with a name matching your search. It doesn't know that you only want to see the single subdocument responsible for that document matching your search criteria.

You can tell mongo that you want to see that element with the positional $ operator.

```
db.mgh_facilities.find({"facilities.name": "Foreign exchange assistance"}, {"facilities.$": true})
```

Comment: Thanks NoOutlet for detail explanation also. This solution also worked.

Comment: What if we have to use LIKE clause in the above query? If I use the following query, its returning only one record.   db.mgh_facilities.find({"locations.name": /.*N.*/}, {"locations.$": true})

Comment: Yes, the [positional $ operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) returns "only the first element matching the query document".

Comment: If you must return multiple matching subdocuments, I believe you'll need to use the aggregation pipeline.
Something like:
`db.mgh_facilities.aggregate([ { $unwind: "$locations" }, {$match: {"locations.name": /.*N.*/ } }, {$group: { _id: "$_id", responseCode: {$first: "$responseCode"}, locations: {$push: "$locations"} } }])`
should give you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
db.mgh_facilities.aggregate([
{
    $unwind:"$facilities"    
},
{
    $match:{"facilities.name": "Foreign exchange assistance"}
},{
    $project:{
        _id:0,
        facilities:1
    }
}

])
```

result:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "facilities" : {
                "id" : "11",
                "name" : "Foreign exchange assistance"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: @user1384058 perfect, take a look http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/. Can you tick my answer please?